# Why does $BASH_VERSION works and don't work depending on how I echo it?

Tags: command-line, sh

I am in a sh terminal.

When I do this

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

I get the version printed.

However when I do this

```
echo "`$SHELL -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'`"
```

I got nothing.

I am not an expert on shells but it seems that the last one actually calls the command. For example

```
echo "`$SHELL -c 'ls'`"
```

actually just calls `ls` so I am expecting that the second one just prints the `$BASH_VERSION`.

Any idea why this does not work?

(Also, I found that $SHELL is not listed on `printenv` . I thought that listed the environment variables. why not?

Comment: I think you answered your own question: When `$SHELL` is not set, how do you expect it to return a value? The `$SHELL` variable should be set at login, from the value defined in `/etc/passwd` for the particular user.

Comment: but when I do less in /etc/default/useradd I can see that `SHELL=/bin/sh`  so it seems it is set!

Comment: Also as I wrote when I do the `ls` thing it worked!

Comment: Sorry, missed that - yeah `SHELL=/bin/sh` should work also. Then I can't explain it - on my machine the "nested" command works as expected.

Comment: I found out it is a matter of the user not being recognized. I entered as root and now it is working as expected. My knowledge of shells being small I could not recognize anything fishy...

Comment: /bin/sh is call POSIX shell or system shell usually linked to`dash` which is not `bash` therefor no output.